# Angular2+: how does NgModel / NgControl internally handle updates from view to model?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-ngmodel

I am doing a deep dive into how two-way databinding works. I am currently puzzled by how updates from the view (say, an `input` element) propagate to `NgControl` internally.

In the definition of `ControlValueAccessor` it mentions that `registerOnChange` is responsible for view -> model updates ([docs where they say it](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#registeronchange), and [src](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9729e8f4b91809aaad2957c40265274c456b775c/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L83)). With a simple directive that we may put on the same `input` element as `[(NgModel)]`, e.g. `<input [(NgModel)]=stuff myInspectorDirective>`, I tried playing around with this.

```
constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.ngControl.valueAccessor['onChange'] = () => {}; 
    // uncommenting the above line prevents updates from view to model 
}
```

Uncommenting/commenting the indicated line allows us to allow/block updates from the input element to the model. But I'm puzzled by this because in the source code of [DefaultValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L60), the one used in this example, `onChange` is not really doing anything: `(_:any) => {}`.

So, I would expect that under the hood, e.g. in [ng_model.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts) or in one of the related classes, like `NgControl` or `FormControl`, something happens with the `onChange` function from the ValueAccessor; setting it or wrapping it in another function, maybe a proxy, or whatever. I did not find anything. Then I went on looking for some code where listeners (for the `input` event, more explicitly) are explicitly bound to the input element, but no luck either.

I noticed that the [`OnChanges` function calls `_setValue`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L187), but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction when diving into the internals of change detection, as I would expect the listening to changes in the DOM to be related to `ControlValueAccessors` and/or `FormControl/AbstractControl`

Anyone feels like elaborating on how this works? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ControlValueAccessor.registerOnChange is provided by the NgForm.

1) NgModel is registered in NgForm (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts)

```
in NgModel.ngOnChanges: this._setUpControl calls this.formDirective.addControl
```

2) NgForm calls shared setUpControl function (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts)

```
import { setUpControl } from './shared';
NgForm.addControl calls setUpControl
```

3) setUpControl registers change event handler (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts)

```
setUpControl calls setUpViewChangePipeline

function setUpViewChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  dir.valueAccessor !.registerOnChange((newValue: any) => {
    control._pendingValue = newValue;
    control._pendingChange = true;
    control._pendingDirty = true;

    if (control.updateOn === 'change') updateControl(control, dir);
  });
}
```